# React Native ScrollView not allowed to add as if it's deprecated

Tags: react-native, scrollview

After I add it, it works fine, but while typing, it's showing as if it's deprecated.

See the image below to know what I mean.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong of it's acting weird?

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` is **NOT** deprecated component in React Native https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview

[image: react-native 0.64.1 scrollview]